# How do I fix E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am receiving the error "E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)"

This seems to be a well documented issue, that there are too many instances of mediaplayer playing, but I am having trouble actually fixing it or finding guides to fix it.

My code is supposed to play a chime on button click,(click1.start();), but they are all piling up. using stop(); breaks the mediaplayer.

Here is my full code for the class:

'''

```
package com.example.snapwordslista;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class activity_level1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button level1back;
    MediaPlayer click2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);

        click2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.btn_jingle2);

        level1back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level1back);
        level1back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(activity_level1.this, MainActivity.class));
                click2.start();

            }

        });
    }'''
```

Answer (score 0):

prepare before calling play

```
    if(player.isPlaying){
        player.stop()
    }
    player.prepare()
    player.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try as you suggested, but now it's pulling an error and telling me: "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown". Any idea why? Thanks.